# How can I insert data into the database using django form?

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-forms, qr-code

I am trying to use django form to insert some information into the database, but the insert is now working properly.

This is for form page with some inputs that I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- /Css -->
<link rel = "stylesheet"    type = "text/css"    href = "../static/survey.css" />
<!-- /Css -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Preencha a pesquisa de satisfação</title>

<style>
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=submit] {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
          padding: 10px 10px;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 4px;
          cursor: pointer;
          float: right;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover {
          background-color: #45a049;
        }

        .col-25 {
          float: left;
          width: 50%;
          margin-top: 6px;
        }

        .col-75 {
          float: left;
          width: 100%;
          margin-top: 5px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row:after {
          content: "";
          display: table;
          clear: both;
        }
        </style>
<!-- /Fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet'>   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- /Fonts -->
 </head>

 <body>

    <h2>Pesquisa de satisfação</h2>
    <p>Avalie a sua experiência em nosso restaurante e nos ajude a melhor o atendimento.</p>
    <div class="container">

      <h2>{{ note }}</h2>

      <form class="formSurvey" action="{% url 'servicesurvey' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ surveyform }}

      <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Voltar</a>
    </div>
    </body> </html>
```

view.py with the function servicesurvey that calls the POST method and return the render.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SurveyForm
from .models import Survey


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'survey/home.html')

def servicesurvey(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
filled_form = SurveyForm(request.POST)
if filled_form.is_valid():
    note = 'Obrigado por responder nossa pesquisa'
    new_form = SurveyForm()
return render(request, 'survey/servicesurvey.html', {'surveyform': new_form, 'note':note})

else:
    form = SurveyForm()
    return render(request, 'survey/servicesurvey.html', {'surveyform':form})


def qrcode(request):
    return render(request, 'survey/qrcode.html')
```

models.py with the 2 inputs that I am trying to save at my database.

```
from django.db import models

class Survey(models.Model):
    aboutTheService = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    aboutTheFood = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: you should use `filled_form.save()` in the block `if filled_form.is_valid():`

Comment: Can you show the code for `SurveyForm`?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code snippet as it's now totally unclear what belongs where. But yes, as @PRMoureu says, if you don't `save()` anything, nothing will get saved.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Roseman! It works!!